# Unrolling nested for loop in C

Tags: c

I am new to unrolling loop. I am trying the optimize it by unrolling but I am not sure how to approach this. It would be a great help if someone could show me a simple way unroll it. Thanks!

```
 for(k=0;k<SIZE;k++){
     X_Real[k] = X_Imag[k] = 0.0;

           for(n=0;n<SIZE;n++){
               ph1 = ((twoPI*k*n)/SIZE);
               X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[n]*cos(ph1);
               X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[n]*sin(ph1);
           }

           X[k] = sqrt((X_Real[k]*X_Real[k])+(X_Imag[k]*X_Imag[k]));
       }
```

The SIZE would be flexible depending on the data point I use which is either 1000 or 1 million.

Comment: What makes you think loop unrolling is going to help?

Comment: Is this for an academic exercise or your own curiosity? If not, let compiler optimizations handle loop unrolling. There's not much to it other than typing practice: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/loop-unrolling/

Comment: Loop unrolling is a technique used when the overhead of the loop is significant compared to the small amount of code within the loop. That's not the case here as the loop contains function calls (*sin*, *cos*, *sqrt*). It is unlikely to result in a measurable improvement.

Comment: In this case maybe the correct way to increase performance is to use complex.h instead? I'd at least give it a try, see if it improves speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of just the inner loop (n-loop) is shown below (regardless if useful):

```
   for(n=0;n<SIZE-4;n+=4){

       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*n)/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[n]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[n]*sin(ph1);
 
       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*(n+1))/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[(n+1)]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[(n+1)]*sin(ph1);
      
       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*(n+2))/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[(n+2)]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[(n+2)]*sin(ph1);
      
       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*(n+3))/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[(n+3)]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[(n+3)]*sin(ph1);
       
       stored=n+3;
   }

   for(n=stored+1;n<SIZE;n++){
       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*n)/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[n]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[n]*sin(ph1);
   }
```

COMMENT:

- Code optimization is a huge topic. Compiler optimization (with all
  best flags) is said to usually be better than naive manual (human)
  code optimization.
- Anyway, also not a reason, never to take "it" into account. ("it" refers to manual loop unrolling or also manual code optimization).

Just a further idea, something like below (can still be improved), and then (always) perform 4 multiplications by ONE intrinsic instruction, with using _mm256_mul_pd. (... and then you can unroll again to n+=16). Anyway, here, sin and cos will "drag down" performance too much. Maybe, you find a fast vectorized version (of sin and cos), or if the range of k and n (==SIZE?!) is always the same, you can precompute and provide it in an optimal order (to avoid cache misses). To come back to the topic, "Loop unrolling" can prepare for a vectorized version of the code. Anyway further aspects are out-of-scope (and sin & cos are the bottle-neck here).

```
  v=(twoPI*k)/(double)SIZE; 
  for(n=0;n<SIZE-4;n+=4){

       ph0 = v*n;
       ph1 = v*(n+1);
       ph2 = v*(n+2);
       ph3 = v*(n+3);

       s0a=Signal1[n]*cos(ph0);
       s0b=Signal1[n]*sin(ph0);

       s1a=Signal1[(n+1)]*cos(ph1);
       s1b=Signal1[(n+1)]*sin(ph1);

       s2a=Signal1[(n+2)]*cos(ph2);
       s2b=Signal1[(n+2)]*sin(ph2);

       s3a=Signal1[(n+3)]*cos(ph3);
       s3b=Signal1[(n+3)]*sin(ph3);

       X_Real[k]+=s0a+s1a+s2a+s3a;
       X_Imag[k]+=s0b+s1b+s2b+s3b;
       
       stored=n+3;
   }

   for(n=stored+1;n<SIZE;n++){
       ph1 = ((twoPI*k*n)/SIZE);
       X_Real[k]=X_Real[k]+Signal1[n]*cos(ph1);
       X_Imag[k]=X_Imag[k]+Signal1[n]*sin(ph1);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to unrolling loop. I am trying the optimize it by unrolling

## Leave such optimizations to your C compiler.

If your compiler is [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/):

- read carefully the documentation about [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)
- try several compiler options [related to optimizations](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), and benchmark your program. If on Linux, read [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)
- compile your C code (in file `foo.c`) with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` and look into the emitted `foo.s` assembly file
- if these optimizations are not enough, write your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to optimize even more. You'll need to understand [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) (a central internal representation in GCC)

---

If you can upgrade or change your hardware, or can redesign your software, consider using [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) to run some code on your GPGPU

---

If your compiler is [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/), study its source code and improve it.

---

Both GCC and Clang are [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software) compilers for C, you are allowed to improve them.

### In all cases, [profile your code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) before spending efforts on manual optimizations

See also the [DECODER](https://www.decoder-project.eu/) and [CompCert](https://compcert.org/) projects, and the [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) static source code analyzer (they could be adapted to do such optimizations)

**Consider also generating C or C++ code**, like the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project do (or on Linux like [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) does also with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) on the generated [plugin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing))), and like explained in [this blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/). Or **generate machine code at runtime** with [asmjit](https://asmjit.com/) or [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/). You could use [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) methods and [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) techniques.

For large data, consider transforming your loop into [multi-threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) code (on Linux see [pthreads(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html)...), or [OpenACC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenACC).

Manual optimizations like the one you consider may change the precision of the result (sometimes, the computed numbers becomes meaningless). See the [Fluctuat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuat) and [CADNA](http://cadna.lip6.fr/) projects, and the [floating point guide](https://floating-point-gui.de/) website.

#### Read also [ACM SIGPLAN](https://sigplan.org/) conference papers dedicated to optimizations.

NB. It could happen that you'll spend months of efforts to gain less than a few percents of performance. Discuss with your manager/boss/client if it is worth that effort. Be also aware of theoretical limitations related to the [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem).

Comment: If you run the code ONLY on your machine or on your server, then you can simply try the compiler option: -march=native